# Asserting a null value via a Scenario outline

Tags: cucumber, rest-assured

I am trying to assert a JSON response null value via the feature file below

```
Scenario Outline: GET incident notifications
    Given I made a GET request for incident notifications for the "<incident>"
    Then I should be able to see "<NotificationID>", "<DateTime>", "<ActionID>", "<Subject>", "<CreatedBy>","<Notes>"
    Examples:
      | incident |NotificationID|DateTime              |ActionID|Subject              |CreatedBy|Notes|
      | 399      | 211          |2017-11-28T14:30:11.01|0       |Logged with Openreach|         |     |
      | 400      | 2112         |2017-11-28T14:35:11.01|1       |Processed at Openreach|Agent   | AgentNotes    |
```

this is my step definition-

```
assertThat(webModel.getRestServices().response.getBody().path("CreatedBy[0]"),is(CreatedBy));
        assertThat(webModel.getRestServices().response.getBody().path("Notes[0]"),is(Notes));
```

this is the error assertion error i get-

```
java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected: is ""
     but: was null
```

I could get this thing working by asserting to `nullValue()` however, the 2nd run will fail as it has to take the parameter from the feature file. 
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we give any parameter as blank in the feature file, its taken as null. That's the reason you are getting this error as it is comparing null with a String.
We can solve this problem by doing a null or empty check before the assert. If the value is null, it would skip the assertion otherwise it will assert.

Comment: Thanks for the message Neha. Yes the Try catch block works. Just wondering if there is any other way.

Comment: I am not talking about try/catch. I am thinking if u can use if condition to check whether the value is null or not. In case not null, execute the assert.

Comment: Ah if else statements. Yes yes got it. Thank you.